# remove mistakenly committed large files from commit history

Tags: git

How do you remove mistakenly committed large files from commit history? Git won't push any more commits to remote until I remove problematic files. I've since attempted to remove them but they exist in previous commits.

**Note**: I do not need the large files anymore in project.

On `git push origin my-branch` I get:

```
remote: warning: File public/images/reserve_assets/myfile.tif is 63.60 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 0c08ce8916353c82c7328a241a40c8ca
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File public/images/reserve_assets/myotherfile.tif is 107.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Then

```
! [remote rejected] my-branch -> my-branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:RepoOwner/myrepo.git'
```

---

I've tried `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f myfile.tif' HEAD` which performs the rewrites across the commit history. It outputs

```
Rewrite 1cd9b031d047d4270ff8b488b3b5e8db2905c687 (87/93) (12 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
```

But then says `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/my-branch' is unchanged`. It seems like it's rewriting and removing from the history but I still cannot push.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had other files which were large too. You cannot remove a single file at a time via `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD` as each time it creates a single backup.

Removing the entire problematic folder via `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/folder' HEAD` with additional `-f` to force former backup rewrite does the trick (assuming you've tried previously with removing a single file)

Comment: Actually, you *can* remove one file at a time. You just *shouldn't* because filter-branch is so slow. It also goes much faster if you use the `--index-filter`, for which you must use `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch` instead of plain `rm -f` (the rest of the rules are pretty similar).